# C# - print a C/C++ formatted string (%d, %s...)

Tags: c#

I got a string coming from a native library, formatted to be printed with printf ; args are decalred with %d instead of {0}. Is there an easy way to print them in C# ?

Thanks.

EDIT: I was not clear enough, I have 2 %d in my string, replacing %d by {0} would make every %d print the same value. I got a char *s and an IntPtr p. p is pointing to the start of the args. I need to print for the first %d the int pointed to by p, and for the second %d print the int pointed to by p + 1. This was for a debug purpose, so I just printed the 3 infos separately, but I hopped there was a cleaner way. Thank you stackoverflow..

Comment: Do you get parameters as well? Then you can `string.Replace` them with c# *format specifiers* and then just use `string.Format`

Comment: Use [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+printf&oq=c%23+printf&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58j0l4.6063j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) Luke ;-)

Comment: I'll try that, thank you

Comment: @Flater [third](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19274/A-printf-implementation-in-C) link, c# printf implementation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sprintf in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313006/sprintf-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use string.replace to swap out the bits you want? For example,

```
string myNewString = myOldString.Replace("%d", "{0}");
```

Then you can simply use string.format